# how to format date using XQuery

Tags: xquery

i have date showing like the following

```
01-Nov-2012 12:00:00 AM
```

and i want to show the if the date is like above than

```
01-Nov-2012
```

this comes for few data only not for all,

How to do this in Xquery.

Please help

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
fn:replace("01-Nov-2012 12:00:00 AM", "\s.*", "")
```

It replaces the space and everything after with the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either:

```
tokenize(/test,' ')[1]
```

or

```
substring-before(/test,' ')
```

With `/test` being replaced with the appropriate path to the date.

Answer (score -1):

It is so simple.

```
convert(VARCHAR(10),datetoformate,106)
```

thats it